# How to convert JSON object to varchar2 using PL/JSON

Tags: oracle, plsql, pljson

I need to convert json object to varchar using PL/JSON library. For an example,

```
declare
mapData     json;
text        varchar2(20)
begin

json := 'json object';
text := convert_to_varchar(json);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know that your JSON will fit into a `varchar2`:

```
text := mapData.to_char();
```

This method is clearly defined in the JSON type declaration -- https://github.com/pljson/pljson/blob/master/src/json.typ#L56

Comment: Any idea what would happen if your JSON looked like this: "Number": "0000000000" ?
I'm not sure if the quotations should be there.  But is there a method to get back the values within the quotes or should I do a replace on the quotes?

Comment: Honestly, no. If the data really came in quoted, then it should be interpreted as a string. But if value wasn't quoted, then you'd just have `0` as the parsed value.